# facebook connect login, request permission to different fields

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to request permission to user data with the code but this line of code only works if the user is already authorised.

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,name,timezone,location,email');
```

But its only showing the id and name as its only requesting User basic information.

I have added the option in the app under User & Friend Permissions: with email,
But this did not help.

How do i request permission for this?

I only need this as i want to match up users facebook id to their email address in my user table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the email column is bot being returned, there could be an issue with your access token. Run your access token thru: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to see if it really does have access to the email column.  Also you can use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer to run Graph API queries directly, this tool has saved me tonnes of time!  Good luck.